# packages not found

Tags: android, sdk

In android sdk, I have downloaded Sources for Android SDK. Hence, now I have source code of libraries provided in the SDK.

However, a project that I downloaded from GrepCode imports 'android.media.Audiosystem'. I found that the file is not present in my sdk directory, hence it is not found in the project. How is this possible? It cannot be third party as it is placed under 'android.media' path which is path of sdk libraries.

There may be more files like these in the project. Why is this happening and how can I resolve it, i.e., make my SDK contain more files than it already does?

Edit : I am using SDK for Android version 6.0
[image: Image of SDK download]

Comment: Does the "GrepCode" project uses gradle to import libraries ?

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.0_r1/com/android/voicedialer/RecognizerEngine.java?av=f
This project uses android.speech.srec folder, which is not present in my SDK. I don't know if it uses gradle.

Comment: I think you required API Level 5 to access this class.

Comment: @HareshChhelana I have API level 6.0

Comment: Why aren't you using the latest [revision](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/5.1.1_r1/)

Comment: @IbrahimMAATKI in my code I have used SDK of the latest version (6.0).
In the link you have shared, I can see media directory does contain 'Audiosystem.java'. It is however not there in my machine. I've attached image showing SDK download in the question edit. Is there something else I need to download?

Comment: @kshubham07 you should download Google APIs... Generally when developping an android application you should always download the google apis

Answer (score 0):

You can not see that class because it is not accessible.

[HERE](http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/AudioSystem.java) you can find its source code:

```
package android.media;

/**
 * @hide
 */
public class AudioSystem {
}
```

Since that class is `@hide`, it is not exported to the SDK. That class is not even documented in [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) (you can find *AudioManager.java* but not *AudioSystem.java*)

I'm not sure how that class is being used on the project that you imported.